# Multiple Android Developer Accounts

Tags: android, account

I have an Android Developer account for my company (but associated with my mail and credit card).
I'd like to create a new developer account for personal use.
Its legal to have multiple developer accounts under the same physical person? I don't find that information in the Android developer license agreement

Thanks in advance

Comment: I imagine they wouldn't mind another $25.  I'm not sure there are any legal guidelines concerning that.

Comment: we can have the another developer account or not..??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done that and they had no problem with it.  If you need to transfer the publisher of an application, they have an online form to do that - however it can take a couple of days to go through.

Comment: your old account continued after migration?

Comment: Yes,  I still have my account - the only thing that moved was the application moved over to the new account

Comment: Thanks for reply. How many days it took to transfer? and did u face any problems? could you please tell how did to contact market team? Thanks a lot..

Comment: Here's one page I found on how you can transfer apps from one account to another and it includes the link to contact the market team. [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139626?hl=en)